# Creating New HTML Elements in JavaScript get error in WordPress

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

I want to show a message in element in page of wordpress(if parameter "message" in url have a value ).for this purpose i installed "Header and Footer Scripts" plugin.and write this code in "insert script to ":

```
<script>
function getUrlParameter(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, '\\[').replace(/[\]]/, '\\]');
    var regex = new RegExp('[\\?&]' + name + '=([^&#]*)');
    var results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return results === null ? '' : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, ' '));
};

if(getUrlParameter('message'))
{
const para = document.createElement("p");
const node = document.createTextNode(getUrlParameter('message'));
para.appendChild(node);

const element = document.getElementsByClassName("entry-content");
element.appendChild(para);

}
</script>
```

but not working. and get error :

> ?message=ثبت انجام شد:291 Uncaught TypeError: element.appendChild is not a function
> at ?message=ثبت انجام شد:291

[image: view of page]

note:I used embed code plugin instead of "Header and Footer Scripts" plugin.My problem was solved.

Comment: You seem to be having a few errors, please check your console.

Comment: ohh yes,i eddited my question.

Comment: Yes, that is what i expected. `getElementsByClassName` returns a collection not a single element. So you need to access its content via `element[0].appendChild(para);` or whatever index you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`element = document.getElementsByClassName("entry-content")` returns a nodelist of elements and not a single one. therefore calling element.appendChild(para) will not work.

You need to iterate over this nodelist. One possible way would be to use `QuerySelectorAll` instead of `getElementsByClassName` :

```
document.querySelectorAll('.entry-content').forEach(element => {
    element.appendChild(para);
```

})

Comment: thanks.error has been fixed.but out put is empty: <p>&nbsp;</p>